# JavaScript Promise return value from function

Tags: javascript, promise

Relatively new to JavaScript Promises.

Trying to call a function - checktheData(recordidGuid) from within a Promise
and use the result in a .then chain.

The last line of the checktheData function is:
return outcomeString

My problem is that the result of the promise is "undefined", yet when I output it to the console in the checktheData function it is as expected

I know I need to add a return statement, but where please?

Simple code:

```
function masterDeploy(PrimaryControl){
    var formContext = PrimaryControl;   
    formContext.data.refresh(true);     
    var recordidGuid = ""
    recordidGuid = formContext.data.entity.getId();
    var loggedinuser = 
    Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().userSettings.userId;
    recordidGuid = recordidGuid.replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
    loggedinuser = loggedinuser.replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
    var outcomeString = ""
    var checkOutcome = false;

let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {       
    resolve(checktheData(recordidGuid))     
});
promise.then(       
    result => {
        console.log(promise);           
    }
),
promise.catch(
    function (error){
    DisplayError(error)}
);
return // stops here whilst debugging

if (checkOutcome == true){
    var alertStrings = { confirmButtonLabel: "Close", text: outcomeString, title: "Data check failed" };
    var alertOptions = { height: 500, width: 1000 };
    Xrm.Navigation.openAlertDialog(alertStrings, alertOptions).then(
    function success(result) {                  
        return;
    },
    function (error) {
        DisplayError(error)
    });
        }
else{
    if(checkOutcome == false){
        //2. Create the learner journal url     
        buildLearnerEntryURL(recordidGuid,loggedinuser)
        if(checkOutcome == false){
            //3. Create refinery user and enrol on courses
            createUserandEnrol(recordidGuid,loggedinuser)
            if(checkOutcome == false){
                //4. Create Learning Aims
                createLearningAims(recordidGuid)
            }           
        };
    };
}
formContext.data.refresh(true);
//Set text to be a concatenated summary of actions completed or skipped
alertStrings = { confirmButtonLabel: "Close", text: "Deployment completed etc etc", title: "Deployment Completed" };
Xrm.Navigation.openAlertDialog(alertStrings, alertOptions).then(
function success(result) {      
    return;
},
function (error) {
    DisplayError(error)
});
};


function checktheData(recordidGuid){
var outcomeString = ""
var checkOutcome = "false"; 
var str = "";
Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveRecord("new_apprenticeshipflight", recordidGuid, "?$select=new_flighttype,new_programmelearningaimreference,new_apprenticeshipoverallaimreference,_new_mentor_value,_new_enrolledstandard_value,_new_clonelinkid_value,new_plannedstartdate,new_plannedenddate,crd80_overideendcalc,_new_contact_value,_new_apprenticeshipprogramme_value,_new_employer_value,_crd80_locationcontact_value,crd80_headofficedelivery,crd80_learningjournalurl,crd80_refineryid,crd80_addresstouse,_crd80_placementemployer_value,crd80_employeraddresstext,&$expand=new_Contact($select=emailaddress1,firstname,lastname),new_EnrolledStandard($select=crd80_learningjournalform),crd80_PlacementEmployer($select=name, accountid, address1_postalcode,address2_postalcode),crd80_LocationContact($select=emailaddress1,fullname,telephone1),new_Employer($select=name,address1_postalcode,address2_postalcode),new_Mentor($select=new_homepostcode),new_ApprenticeshipProgramme($select=crd80_learnerteamsiteurl)").then( 
    function success(result) {              
        if (result["new_flighttype"] == 100000001 && result["new_flighttype"] == null){outcomeString = outcomeString + "This must be a learner type flight"; checkOutcome = true};
        
//other lines removed for clarity

        console.log(outcomeString)
        return outcomeString
        
        
    })  
}
```

Comment: Could you attach also the code from `checktheData`?

Comment: What's the point of the Promise if it resolves immediately? Is `checktheData` async?

Comment: checkdata now added.
This is the first step of a number of checks that need to be chained to give me an overall data check output from a number of sources

Comment: First of all, `return a, b` will not work as you expect. Plus, returning inside a callback will have no effect at all. You are not returning anything from `checktheData` itself.

Comment: your `checktheData` is async it only returns data when  `Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveRecord` is fulfilled

Comment: thank you Chris. I will research how to achieve what you have said is incorrect then.

Comment: Here's a short primer I wrote: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/kpj204wL/

Comment: Thank you Chris. Your primer indicates I have got this totally wrong and need to adopt a completely different strategy.

Comment: BTW, that `if` condition is never going to be true. Did you mean `||` instead of `&&`?

Comment: `"false"` is a strange value to use, when later you assign `true`. Use `false` (without quotes).

Comment: thanks for the notes re if and false. false was purposely set as a string to test, the "if" is however a mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveRecord` return a promise, so you can just return it from `checktheData()`.

What you need to handle is basically just to call the `checktheData()` and use `.then()` and `.catch()` for the result.

Example:

```js
function masterDeploy(PrimaryControl) {
  var formContext = PrimaryControl;
  formContext.data.refresh(true);
  var recordidGuid = "";
  recordidGuid = formContext.data.entity.getId();
  var loggedinuser = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().userSettings.userId;
  recordidGuid = recordidGuid.replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
  loggedinuser = loggedinuser.replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
  var outcomeString = "";

  checktheData()
    .then(checkOutcome => {
      if (checkOutcome == true) {
        var alertStrings = {
          confirmButtonLabel: "Close",
          text: outcomeString,
          title: "Data check failed",
        };
        var alertOptions = { height: 500, width: 1000 };
        Xrm.Navigation.openAlertDialog(alertStrings, alertOptions).then(
          function success(result) {
            return;
          },
          function (error) {
            DisplayError(error);
          }
        );
      } else {
        if (checkOutcome == false) {
          //2. Create the learner journal url
          buildLearnerEntryURL(recordidGuid, loggedinuser);
          if (checkOutcome == false) {
            //3. Create refinery user and enrol on courses
            createUserandEnrol(recordidGuid, loggedinuser);
            if (checkOutcome == false) {
              //4. Create Learning Aims
              createLearningAims(recordidGuid);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      formContext.data.refresh(true);
      //Set text to be a concatenated summary of actions completed or skipped
      alertStrings = {
        confirmButtonLabel: "Close",
        text: "Deployment completed etc etc",
        title: "Deployment Completed",
      };

      Xrm.Navigation.openAlertDialog(alertStrings, alertOptions)
        .then(function success(result) {
          return;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          DisplayError(error);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

function checktheData(recordidGuid) {
  var outcomeString = "";
  var checkOutcome = "false";
  var str = "";
  Xrm.WebApi.online
    .retrieveRecord(
      "new_apprenticeshipflight",
      recordidGuid,
      "?$select=new_flighttype,new_programmelearningaimreference,new_apprenticeshipoverallaimreference,_new_mentor_value,_new_enrolledstandard_value,_new_clonelinkid_value,new_plannedstartdate,new_plannedenddate,crd80_overideendcalc,_new_contact_value,_new_apprenticeshipprogramme_value,_new_employer_value,_crd80_locationcontact_value,crd80_headofficedelivery,crd80_learningjournalurl,crd80_refineryid,crd80_addresstouse,_crd80_placementemployer_value,crd80_employeraddresstext,&$expand=new_Contact($select=emailaddress1,firstname,lastname),new_EnrolledStandard($select=crd80_learningjournalform),crd80_PlacementEmployer($select=name, accountid, address1_postalcode,address2_postalcode),crd80_LocationContact($select=emailaddress1,fullname,telephone1),new_Employer($select=name,address1_postalcode,address2_postalcode),new_Mentor($select=new_homepostcode),new_ApprenticeshipProgramme($select=crd80_learnerteamsiteurl)"
    )
    .then(function success(result) {
      if (
        result["new_flighttype"] == 100000001 &&
        result["new_flighttype"] == null
      ) {
        outcomeString = outcomeString + "This must be a learner type flight";
        checkOutcome = true;
      }

      //other lines removed for clarity

      console.log(outcomeString);
      return outcomeString;
    });
}
```

Another example with async/await approach.

```js
async function masterDeploy(PrimaryControl) {
  var formContext = PrimaryControl;
  formContext.data.refresh(true);
  var recordidGuid = "";
  recordidGuid = formContext.data.entity.getId();
  var loggedinuser = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().userSettings.userId;
  recordidGuid = recordidGuid.replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
  loggedinuser = loggedinuser.replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
  var outcomeString = "";

  const checkOutcome = await checktheData();

  if (checkOutcome == true) {
    var alertStrings = {
      confirmButtonLabel: "Close",
      text: outcomeString,
      title: "Data check failed",
    };
    var alertOptions = { height: 500, width: 1000 };
    try {
      const result = await Xrm.Navigation.openAlertDialog(
        alertStrings,
        alertOptions
      );
    } catch (err) {
      DisplayError(err);
    }
  } else {
    if (checkOutcome == false) {
      //2. Create the learner journal url
      buildLearnerEntryURL(recordidGuid, loggedinuser);
      if (checkOutcome == false) {
        //3. Create refinery user and enrol on courses
        createUserandEnrol(recordidGuid, loggedinuser);
        if (checkOutcome == false) {
          //4. Create Learning Aims
          createLearningAims(recordidGuid);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  formContext.data.refresh(true);
  //Set text to be a concatenated summary of actions completed or skipped
  alertStrings = {
    confirmButtonLabel: "Close",
    text: "Deployment completed etc etc",
    title: "Deployment Completed",
  };

  try {
    const result = await Xrm.Navigation.openAlertDialog(
      alertStrings,
      alertOptions
    );
  } catch (err) {
    DisplayError(err);
  }
}

async function checktheData(recordidGuid) {
  var outcomeString = "";
  var checkOutcome = "false";
  var str = "";
  const result = await Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveRecord(
    "new_apprenticeshipflight",
    recordidGuid,
    "?$select=new_flighttype,new_programmelearningaimreference,new_apprenticeshipoverallaimreference,_new_mentor_value,_new_enrolledstandard_value,_new_clonelinkid_value,new_plannedstartdate,new_plannedenddate,crd80_overideendcalc,_new_contact_value,_new_apprenticeshipprogramme_value,_new_employer_value,_crd80_locationcontact_value,crd80_headofficedelivery,crd80_learningjournalurl,crd80_refineryid,crd80_addresstouse,_crd80_placementemployer_value,crd80_employeraddresstext,&$expand=new_Contact($select=emailaddress1,firstname,lastname),new_EnrolledStandard($select=crd80_learningjournalform),crd80_PlacementEmployer($select=name, accountid, address1_postalcode,address2_postalcode),crd80_LocationContact($select=emailaddress1,fullname,telephone1),new_Employer($select=name,address1_postalcode,address2_postalcode),new_Mentor($select=new_homepostcode),new_ApprenticeshipProgramme($select=crd80_learnerteamsiteurl)"
  );

  if (
    result["new_flighttype"] == 100000001 &&
    result["new_flighttype"] == null
  ) {
    outcomeString = outcomeString + "This must be a learner type flight";
    checkOutcome = true;
  }

  //other lines removed for clarity

  console.log(outcomeString);
  return outcomeString;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, can you tell me if it would work for my situation, which I no realise I should have explained more fully.
The initial let promise = new Promise etc is in function masterDeploy()
This function is to be used to chain together the results of 5 subsidiary functions all returning data to masterDeploy()
function checktheData(recordidGuid) is just one of these functions.

Comment: @MartinHutchins, you may show us the code structure and you can remove unnecessary details. I cannot understand the details from your comment.

Comment: @MartinHutchins, it doesn't work in your codes because you need to return `Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveRecord`, otherwise you cannot get the return value from the promise when it fullfilled.

Comment: I have added the calling function to my original post

Comment: @MartinHutchins, I updated my answer with two examples. you can have a look at the first example to see how I chain the promise. I didn't test the codes, so there may be some syntax error.

Comment: Thank you so much. I need to modify it slightly but I am now getting results passed back to masterdeploy. I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: @MartinHutchins, you are welcome, I am happy to help. You may have a look at promise in js because in your case, people usually use async/await syntax instead because the codes are more readable and async/await is based on promise.